# Redux Observables: General way to return non-observable in mergeMap?

Tags: redux-observable

observable.

In my epic, I just want to call a 3rd party library for scheduling a push notification on iOS (I'm using react native):

```
import 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

import * as calendarActions from '../ducks/calendar';

export default function cancelRSVPIfSignedIn(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(calendarActions.CANCEL_RSVP)
    .filter(() => store.getState().user.signedIn)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      return new Observable(observer => {
        const meetupId = action.payload;
        PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: meetupId });
        observer.next(meetupId);
      });
    })
    .map(action => calendarActions.rsvpAdded(action.payload));
};
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if this is the most common approach to return an Observable and inside it just to call `observer.next()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to create an Observable that wraps non-Observable code and you **want to observe the results of that code**--that's the crucial part.

If you don't care about whether the side effect produces anything, errors, or if it completes asynchronously or not, then wrapping it in a custom Observable isn't neccesary. You could just use the [`.do()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) operator instead.

```
export default function cancelRSVPIfSignedIn(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(calendarActions.CANCEL_RSVP)
    .filter(() => store.getState().user.signedIn)
    .do(action => PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: action.payload }))
    .map(action => calendarActions.rsvpAdded(action.payload));
};
```

---

There's one missing thing I want to point out in your code, however. You never call `observer.complete()` which means you're accidentally leaking the subscription to that custom Observable. Every time a new `CANCEL_RSVP` comes in another one will be created and subscribed to (`mergeMap`) with the previous sticking around even though it has no work left to be done.

Remember to always call `observer.complete()` when you're done, unless of course your Observable intentionally never completes.

(also, it emits `observer.next(meetupId)` but then later `.map(action =>` but that might just be a typo in this question, not your apps code)

Comment: Awesome! "Do" sounds exactly like what I want. Thanks for the tip about complete too!